# To code an App like Candy Crush in iOS and Android

Tags: ios, ios6, ios6.1

I was wondering if the standard iOS widgets is able to code a Candy Crush-like app? I'm confused about how to program for a Candy Crush-like app. I'm used to the normal dialog boxes and views but have not progressed further from those.

What iOS framework is require? Some graphics or 2d framework?

Poliquin

Comment: Hi guys, JEff Wolski answered my query perfectly. Why is my question, not a real question? It's not specific because I have no idea what to expect. It's not to start a flame war.

Comment: As written, the question is too vague to be a good fit for StackOverflow. Would be better to ask in any iOS game programming forum. The answers are a matter of opinion, rather than objectively correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try Cocos2d.

Here is an introductory tutorial.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial